# How to link translated pypy/rpython to external jvm libraries?

Tags: python, jvm, pypy, rpython

I am trying to compile RPython code to JVM using pypy's translator toolchain.

However, there are many CPython libraries that are not supported, like urllib.urlopen() fails to translate to jvm.

Is it possible for me to have the jvm translation backend link calls like urllib.urlopen() and random.random() to jvm/jar implementations that I provide to it, compiled from java?

What's the best way to enable my RPython translated to JVM to be able to do more of what users would expect from Python?

Comment: I think you just need to define the functions to call appropriate Java counterparts. Write appropriate replacement modules (only the pieces you need) and place them so that the translator will find them.

Comment: You appear to confuse RPython and Python. Or does the RPython code you speak of happen to be the Python interpreter written in RPython?

Comment: By Python, I'm referring to standard python, which allows you to import urllib and use it. The Pypy translator toolchain only supports the RPython subset of the Python language, so it can only translate RPython. I want the RPython code I write and get translated to JVM to be able to use libraries like urllib and others, or an alternative.

Comment: @user1678406 Then you will have to write that alternative. RPython is not intended as a general purpose programming language. The PyPy developers only use it for writing interpreters, and have only added features/libraries they needed for that purpose. Python's urllib is not RPython, so you can't use it. The RPython compiler has no way of magically guessing what urllib does and hooking it up to Java for you. Extensive libraries for RPython simply **don't exist**, because nobody has written most of them. So if you find something missing in RPython, you generally would have to write it yourself.